# Xamarin.Android using MvvmCross crashes on Activity launch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am currently developing a Xamarin app and all of a sudden my Android app started crashing on LoginActivity. I have researched a lot on "

> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path

" 
Tried things like updating Android SDK, deleting bin and obj folder.  Looking at stacktrace it seems to be an issue with MvvmCross.  Currently I am using 3.5.1 of MvvmCross.

Another fact is that I am the only one in team who is facing this issue.

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
[MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
[MonoDroid]     at md5da1044ae077a2d5a79e87e5c6bedf113.LoginActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at md5da1044ae077a2d5a79e87e5c6bedf113.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:31)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
[MonoDroid]     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
[MonoDroid]         ... 19 more
[MonoDroid]     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
[MonoDroid]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0xa047bf80 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) <0xa2007008 + 0x000b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.App.Activity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) <0xa1018918 + 0x0014f> in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at ACS.FundRaising.Android.MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) <0xa047b4e0 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at ACS.FundRaising.Android.LoginActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) <0xa047b278 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) <0xa116f9b0 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:dd5e6f9d-f207-497c-b5c3-0a2c9dac76e7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
[MonoDroid]     at md5da1044ae077a2d5a79e87e5c6bedf113.LoginActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at md5da1044ae077a2d5a79e87e5c6bedf113.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:31)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
[MonoDroid] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
[MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
[MonoDroid]     ... 18 more
[MonoDroid]     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
[MonoDroid]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
[MonoDroid]         ... 19 more
[MonoDroid]     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref GoogleAnalytics.Core[0xb429abe0] -> System.Net.Http[0xaed233a0]: 3
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref GoogleAnalytics.Core[0xb429abe0] -> System.Core[0xb4387580]: 7
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xaed233a0] -> System[0xb4387760]: 10
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xaed233a0] -> System.Core[0xb4387580]: 8
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[mono-rt] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.cancer.fundraising-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
[mono-rt]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
[mono-rt]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
[mono-rt]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
[mono-rt]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
[mono-rt]   at md5da1044ae077a2d5a79e87e5c6bedf113.LoginActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at md5da1044ae077a2d5a79e87e5c6bedf113.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:31)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
[mono-rt]   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
[mono-rt]       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
[mono-rt]       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
[mono-rt]       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
[mono-rt]       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
[mono-rt]       ... 19 more
[mono-rt]   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[mono-rt]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0xa047bf80 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) <0xa2007008 + 0x000b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.Activity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) <0xa1018918 + 0x0014f> in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at ACS.FundRaising.Android.MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) <0xa047b4e0 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at ACS.FundRaising.Android.LoginActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) <0xa047b278 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) <0xa116f9b0 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:dd5e6f9d-f207-497c-b5c3-0a2c9dac76e7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
[mono-rt]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[mono-rt] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
[mono-rt]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
[mono-rt]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
[mono-rt]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompa
```

Comment: I have tried upgrading to 4.0.0-beta7 in MvvmCross still same problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all packages, restore them again. Also delete your local repo for the java files Xamarin download for Appcompat, and clear your obj and bin folders.

Answer (score 3):

In my case a solution Clean was necessary to get it working.

Comment: @CyprienAutexier no need to Uninstall the app yourself as Visual Studio does it for you before deploying the application on the emulator or the phone.

Comment: It obviously does not remove all files.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved by Re-Cloning the repository.  Still I don't know what caused the issue but I ended up wasting lot of time.  I tried things like;

1. Removing and downloading packages
2. Deleting Obj/Bin
3. Deleting appcompat from android SDK install folder and re-downloading it
4. Using component instead of package

Probably build output generated some garbage resulting in such issue.